# My Volley Request From my android app is reaching the server but data(name, email and password) is not received by the server?

Tags: android, android-volley

it gives me a error - 
com.android.volley.TimeoutError

while data(name , email, pass) is lost somehow.

i cant understand what is happening.

please help

code -

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_REGISTER,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("D - Message - Ashik - ", response);
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("D - Message - Ashik - ", error.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", Sname);
            params.put("email",Semail);
            params.put("password", Spass);
            return params;
        }

    };
    //Toast.makeText(Register.this, Sname + Semail + Spass, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Use     rq.add(postReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)));

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @OrkunKoçyiğit  - i have added the code

Comment: @Vadivel - why is it used could you explain

Comment: If face any network delay we can  extend request time.You can had above code to solve this problem

Comment: @Vadivel - i tried that now it says java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.100.6 (port 80) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Comment: can  you check did you give  internet permission or APi network and your mobile network are same